# PHP - JQuery implement Progress long running request

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have an Zend Framework Application to get Mails form an IMAP Account. This could take a while. So i want to show in frontend how many mails are left to process.

Iam thinking about this solution:

- Object wich processes the Mails is writing the processed amount of mails (int) into an file/db
- While the Script is running, requesting the the content of this file every 20 seconds and show the number to the user

are there better solutions for this with php/javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use flush() to output data to the browser at certain points. Admittedly, this isn't a pretty but you could (should) refactor:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Progress Bar</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Progress bar holder -->
<div id="progress" style="width:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;"></div>
<!-- Progress information -->
<div id="information" style="width"></div>
<?php
// Total processes
$total = 10;

// Loop through process
for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++){
    // Calculate the percentation
    $percent = intval($i/$total * 100)."%";

    // Javascript for updating the progress bar and information
    echo '<script language="javascript">
    document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-color:#ddd;\">&nbsp;</div>";
    document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$i.' row(s) processed.";
    </script>';

    // This is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
    echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

    // Send output to browser immediately
    flush();

    // Sleep one second so we can see the delay
    sleep(1);
}

// Tell user that the process is completed
echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="Process completed"</script>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Code sample is from [W3Shaman](http://w3shaman.com/article/php-progress-bar-script)

Comment: doing `sleep();` is wrong  as you slow things down with no benefits. Just do not `echo()` on each iteration of your loop and you are done. Filling buffer is quite pointless too if you call `flush()`.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com Sleep() is only there for demonstration purposes. Obviously, you would take that out if you're doing it for a specific process.